# Rails: Simple survey with json/xml output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, voting

I want to create a simple app with a webform interface for adding questions and answers. Something like voting. In one form I want to have a textfield for a question and several addable/removable fields for answers.

Is there some gem for that? I have found Surveyor but it is too complex for my needs.

Comment: have you found a solution now?

Comment: yeah, sorry for not checking your answer for so long time

Comment: no proble. just cleaning up a bit here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work through the ["Nested Model Form" tutorials on railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested%20model%20form), then you would have, at least, the backend to create your surveys.

Comment: I followed episode but I am not able to add answers. Everything else is fine ... and how can i render whole survey to json/xml? Is there any option to render nested form set?

Comment: I think you will need to create a method where you render your things to json/xml.